# A differentiable function which is surjective.

Tags: real-analysis

> $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=x^2 \sin(1/x)$, $x\neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$. Prove that f is surjective.

It’s clear that $f$ oscillates between the two parabolas $y=x^2$ and $y=-x^2$ and hence any line parallel the $x$-axis intersects the curve at least once and so $f$ is surjective. Is this a correct way of proving the result? Is there any rigorous way of doing the problem? Specifically, can implicit function theorem be applied to the given function to prove surjectivity? Thankful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f$ is continuous. If we show that $f(x) \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$ and $f(x) \to -\infty$ as $x \to -\infty$ we can conlude that $f$ is surjective ( by IVP of continuous functions). To prove these two fact just use the fact that $\frac {\sin t} t \to 1$ as $t \to 0$.

Comment: Thank you for the nice insight.